# How to extend a component not class in SASS

Tags: html, css, sass, css-selectors

In [this example (under *Extend/Inheritance*)](http://sass-lang.com/guide), it's shown how to extend a predeclared **style**.

```
.message
  border: 1px solid #ccc
  padding: 10px
  color: #333

.success
  @extend .message
  border-color: green
```

I wonder if there's a way to extend a **class**. The reason is that I've got a *nav* and under it I have *ul*. Those are formatted as supposed to but now I'd like to add the class *active* too that takes the style of the *ul* in a *nav* and completes it with a color of the background.

```
nav
  ul
    font-size: 20px

.active
  @extend ???
  background: pinky
```

Is it possible and if so how? I'm not sure what to google for...

Comment: Almost, but not quite. Sass [can `@extend` a regular ol' selector](http://www.sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#extending_complex_selectors) such as a `nav` or `ul` *but* it can't `@extend` a *chained selector*, so `@extend nav ul;` won't work. @Jon Uleis's approach below is probably what you're after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That seems like a very roundabout way of applying a modifier class (`.active`). Usually best practice would be to do it like this:

```
nav
  ul
    font-size: 20px
    &.active
      background: pink
```

Which would compile to `nav ul.active { background: pink }` and style `<nav> <ul class="active"></ul> </nav>`.